# How do I display labels in checkbox grid table?

Tags: webforms

I managed to create table grid with checkboxes, however I can't get the label to display in first column. What am I missing, could you guys help ?

Thanks! [image]

This is what I have in backend

[image]

Update:

Drupal issue: https://www.drupal.org/project/webform/issues/2951650

Comment: Custom tables are not fully supported by the Webform elements.  I would have to see the YAML source to figure out what is happening with your above example.

Comment: @jrockowitz that's just a standard checkboxes field nested within Table element.

Comment: I think you have discovered a completely unexpected and undocumented behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure this out by creating a new custom element. My solution can be downloaded on my Github https://github.com/minnur/webform_checkboxes_table

Comment: But how do I import it in Drupal?

Comment: What do you mean ? You just download it and install as a separate module. If you need to make some customizations you would need to rename it and make the changes in it. I am planning eventually release it on Drupal.org.

Comment: Ok, because I'm managing my installation with Composer